# Not able to import JasperReportsCsvView in a Spring Boot application

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jasper-reports

Following is the snippet of the pom.xml used in our project :

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>r05</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As we could see the respective versions used are *Java (1.8)*, *Jasper Reports(6.6.0)* and *Spring boot (2.0.3.RELEASE)*. 
Is there anything we have been missing or added extra as a dependency? 
Or is it the sequence of dependencies which is affecting the proper import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out [What's New in Spring Framework 5.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x) as per the documentation

> Removed Packages, Classes and Methods 
>   Dropped support: Portlet, Velocity, JasperReports, XMLBeans, JDO, Guava.
>   Recommendation: Stay on Spring Framework 4.3.x for those if needed.

Might help anyone else also. Thank you.